Issue displaying correct values in matrix
I have the following two tables in PowerBI:
Counterparty  Commodity  DealType Delivery Period   Value         Price
MQ             HO         Buy       Nov24            -3.59528     20.6947
MQ             HO         Sell      Nov24            1.243251     20.6947
MQ             HO         Sell      Nov24            1.947759     20.6947
MQ             HO         Sell      Nov24            2.346524     20.6947
MQ             HO         Buy       Dec24            -3.19765     21.4649
MQ             HO         Sell      Dec24            1.123275     21.4649
MQ             HO         Sell      Dec24            1.759798     21.4649
MQ             HO         Sell      Dec24            2.145425     21.4649
JA             HO         Buy       Jul24            -1.65421     21.1075
JA             HO         Buy       Jul24            -3.03272     21.1075
JA             HO         Sell      Jul24            1.597610     21.115
JA             HO         Sell      Jul24            2.575670     21.115
JA             HO         Sell      Jul24            1.751550     21.115

Counterparty  Commodity  DealType Delivery Period   Value         Price
MQ             HO         Buy       Nov24            -3.60305     20.6947
MQ             HO         Sell      Nov24            1.245915     20.6947
MQ             HO         Sell      Nov24            1.951933     20.6947
MQ             HO         Sell      Nov24            2.351525     20.6947
MQ             HO         Buy       Dec24            -3.21755     21.4649
MQ             HO         Sell      Dec24            1.130265     21.4649
MQ             HO         Sell      Dec24            1.770748     21.4649
MQ             HO         Sell      Dec24            2.158775     21.4649
JA             HO         Buy       Nov24            -8.76732     21.0794
JA             HO         Buy       Nov24            -1.60734     21.0794
JA             HO         Buy       Dec24            -1.43772     21.0794
JA             HO         Buy       Dec24            -7.84212     21.0794
JA             HO         Sell      Nov24            8.4061       21.0794
JA             HO         Sell      Nov24            9.14049      21.0794
JA             HO         Sell      Nov24            1.35081      21.0794
JA             HO         Sell      Dec24            1.23526      21.0794
JA             HO         Sell      Dec24            7.6351       21.0794
JA             HO         Sell      Dec24            8.44659      21.0794

In my model view, I have these two tables as my fact tables, and I have two dim tables for Counterparty and Commodity with just the distinct values.
When I create a matrix with this data, I am grouping Counterparty, Commodity, DealType, and Delivery period to be my rows field
Columns field is empty
My Values field is Price (from table1), Price (from table2), Sum of Value (from table1), Sum of Value (from table2)
However, the values are not displaying correctly. Firstly, the Price columns are forced to be aggregated. Secondly, for Counterparty = JA you can see the Delivery Period does not align correctly between the two tables so that will cause issues displaying in the matrix correctly.
My question is, what kind of measure(s) can I create so that my data is grouped and displayed properly?
My expected output (excluding the sums of Value since I am more concerned with the Prices but Feel free to add the sums too):
                                                Price2     Price1
Counterparty Commodity DealType Delivery period
JA           HO        Buy      Dec24             21.0794    21.1075
                                Nov24             21.0794    21.1075
                       Sell     Dec24             21.0794    21.115
                                Nov24             21.0794    21.115
MQ           HO        Buy      Dec24             21.4649    21.4649
                                Nov24             20.6939    20.6939
                       Sell     Dec24             21.4649    21.4649
                                Nov24             20.6939    20.6939


price 1 from the secnd table and price 2 from the first table table? why JA HO sell Dec 24 for prices are 21.0794 and 21.115? we can only find 21.0794 in the second table

@Ryan I think that’s just a typo. But yes so I need to get the group JA HO sell Dec24 from each table and display the price. For JA tho, the date does not align correctly in table 1. In that case, you take the price where it is sell or buy and apply it for Price 1 in the final output

it's better to update the output. We need to find out the logic between the sample data and expected output. If they are not matching, that will make us to provide the wrong answer.

@Ryan it is updated

here is a workaround for you
create two columns in each table
Column = "Table1"
Column = "Table2"

Then combine two tables
Table = UNION(Table1,Table2)


Then create two measures for price
price1 =
MAXX ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Column] = "Table1" ), 'Table'[Price] )

price2 =
MAXX ( FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[Column] = "Table2" ), 'Table'[Price] )


